# XSLT running total for non-siblings

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to calculate a running total for the cost and pages elements in the XML document as below.

Given both cost and pages are children of OrderAmounts I do not know how to complete a running total. I've searched other answers, but could only find references to calculating running totals for sibling elements.

XML

```
<Root>
  <Info>
    <CustomerName>Clay Allen</CustomerName>
    <CustAddr>123 Main St</CustAddr>
    <Date>2018-02-07</Date>
  </Info>
  <Details>
    <AdditionalDetails>
      <OrderDetails>
        <Order>
         <OrderNumber>A1</OrderNumber>
         <OrderAmounts>
           <Cost>100</Cost>
           <Pages>1325</Pages>
         </OrderAmounts>
        </Order>
        <Order>
         <OrderNumber>A2</OrderNumber>
         <OrderAmounts>
           <Cost>75</Cost>
           <Pages>950</Pages>
         </OrderAmounts>
        </Order>
      </OrderDetails>
    </AdditionalDetails>
  </Details>
</Root>
```

My XSL

```
<xsl:for-each select="Root/Details/AdditionalDetails/OrderDetails/Order">
  (Cumulative value: <xsl:variable name="temp1" select="sum(preceding-sibling::Order)+OrderAmounts/Cost"/><xsl:value-of select="$temp1"/>)<br/>
  (Cumulative value: <xsl:variable name="temp2" select="sum(preceding-sibling::Order)+OrderAmounts/Pages"/><xsl:value-of select="$temp2"/>)
  <br/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Which yields the output

```
100
1325

75
950
```

Desired output

```
175
2275
```

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Please (always!) say which version of XSLT you are using. Problems like this are much easier in 2.0 or 3.0 than in 1.0, but no-one wants to find they have wasted time giving a solution for the wrong version.

Comment: Thank you. For future reference this question pertained to XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

'sum()' function needs any nodeset to evaluate the total (they do not need to be siblings), so your issue was to find the right XPATH to select nodes for the sum function. So the following should work.

```
<TotalCosts>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//OrderAmounts/Cost)"/>
</TotalCosts>
<TotalPages>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//OrderAmounts/Pages)"/>
</TotalPages>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to mention why I was using a running total. If pages>1000 we need to add the cost to Total costs. Thus, we need to add a condition to each loop to check the value of pages and then add cost to the variable if applicable. Is this possible as $temp is out of scope after the loop?

Comment: You can store the sum in a variable before the loop and use it inside the loop if the condition applies.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that instead of `sum(preceding-sibling::Order)+OrderAmounts/Cost` you want `sum(preceding-sibling::OrderOrderAmounts/Cost)+OrderAmounts/Cost`

However, this is quadratic in the number of orders, and for XSLT 3.0 you can improve this using `xsl:iterate` to compute a running total:

```
<xsl:iterate select="Order">
  <xsl:param name="cost-so-far" as="xs:decimal" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="pages-so-far" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
  ...
  <xsl:next-iteration>
    <xsl:with-param name="cost-so-far" select="$cost-so-far + xs:decimal(OrderAmounts/Cost)"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="pages-so-far" select="$pages-so-far + xs:decimal(OrderAmounts/Pages)"/> 
  </xsl:next-iteration>
</xsl:iterate>
```